# Use Fabric AND Firebase Crashlytics at the same time

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I want to use Firebase Crashlytics as it's well integrated with the rest of Firebase suite but I also want to use Fabric, partly because they have an iOS app that allows me to track some bugs amongst other things.

For Fabric, you need to create an entry in your Info.plist with your Fabric API key and you have to use a script where you give some API keys as parameters.

For Firebase Crashlytics, you just need `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"`.

So when you tried to run both scripts `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` and `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" key key`, because of your entry in your Info.plist file, you get an error saying it's expecting some keys when running your Firebase Crashlytics script.

Is there a way to use both services at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks. Because of the way our APIs are integrated, you can only use one of Firebase Crashlytics and Fabric Crashlytics. They are the same on the backend, but have slightly different frontend features at this time. We recommend you go with Firebase Crashlytics as it is where we are investing all future feature work.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was keen to use firebase as we use firebase for many other featured but the lack of client side app for crash reporting is quite a problem for us. Plus in Fabric, crashes are really quickly shown while in Firebase it might take a while before they appear on the console.

Comment: @Todd I'm facing the same issue. I removed the Fabric config from the app delegate, the Fabric keys from my Info.plist, only ran "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" with DWARF with DSYM file but I still haven't got a single crash report in Firebase, I've been trying to get one for hours and nothing.